# iOS: Hide UIStackView SubViews

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistackview

I have a small issue in mu UIStackView.
I created a project similar in this guide:

https://medium.com/@nrewik/easy-animation-with-uistackview-8878b2856ae2

and it works perfectly. 
Anyway if in the stackView there is only a subView it disappears on the top-left corner instead to disappear completely from the bottom side.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this problem, it's important to add a leading and trailing constraint to every single subview.